# Kubernetes job pod stuck in PodInitializing but condition says it's initialized

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Job that sometimes has a pod stuck in PodInitializing status:

```
$ kubectl get pod my-job-0-f4n4l
NAME             READY   STATUS            RESTARTS   AGE
my-job-0-f4n4l   0/2     PodInitializing   0          165m
```

However when I run describe, it says the init container ran successfully and the condition says the pod is initialized:

```
$ kubectl describe pod my-job-0-f4n4l
...
Init Containers:
  update-tools:
    ...
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Tue, 30 May 2023 10:49:21 -0700
      Finished:     Tue, 30 May 2023 10:49:21 -0700
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
Containers:
  batch:
    ...
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Events:                      <none>
```

The logs for the init container are empty (as typical when it succeeds):

```
$ kubectl logs my-job-0-f4n4l -c update-tools
```

Any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: Can you show the YAML definition?

Comment: Can you update this question to include a [mcve]? Is there anything of interest in the `Events` section of your `kubectl describe` output?

Comment: @larsks: Unfortunately there are no events. Updated the original post. I'll see if I can concoct a minimal reproducible example, but it's non-trivial since I can't share the container images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the PodInitializing is a red herring. After deleting the pod and letting the Job re-create it, it now shows:

```
Events:
  Warning  Failed     20s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    4s (x2 over 22s)   kubelet            Pulling image "xxx"
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 21s)   kubelet            Failed to pull image "xxx": xxx  Warning
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 21s)   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

And the state is now ImagePullBackOff. Not sure why sometimes it gets stuck in PodInitializing with no Events, but this seems to be a non-deterministic occurrence.